# How can i organize my components? is there any type of convention to do it?

Tags: angular, package, components

I'm learning Angular and i had this problem, I have in the project many components (18 components at now) and I think that my package "components" doesn't enough to organize it, I searched this question without success, or simply I don't know how to find it.

Comment: There is no rigid convention. However, there is common sense of dividing into logically related subfolders. By default the root folder is `src/app`, so for example `src/app/features` can be the root of the feature components, and `src/app/shared` the root of the shared (common) components. And so forth.

Comment: I didn't think about this way, thanks